# Are solutions to the Lagrangian multipliers ($\alpha_i$) in a hard-margin SVM unique?

Tags: svm, lagrange-multipliers

An intermediate step in the derivation of the hard-margin SVM's dual form is as follows:

[image]

I also know that $a_i$ for all points not on the margin boundary is 0, which makes sense; they must be zeroed out to prevent them from being subtracted from the $\max$. However, for points on the margin boundary where $y_i(\langle x_i, w \rangle + b) - 1 = 0$, it looks like it doesn't matter what $a_i$ is since the term is always 0 anyways. Doesn't this mean there are many values of $a_i$ producing the same result? This seems to conflict the interpretation of $a_i$ as how much each point on the boundary "contributes" to the separating hyperplane. Are the $a_i$s solved for in the SVM dual form unique?